# Connecting to Sharepoint 2010 via DOTCMIS : exception authentication provider

Tags: c#, apache, sharepoint, cmis, dotcmis

I am trying to connect to sharepoint 2010 using DOTCMIS in C#. 
In a very similar fashion to this question:

[Connecting via CMIS (dotCMIS) to SP2010: exception unauthorised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941809/connecting-via-cmis-dotcmis-to-sp2010-exception-unauthorised)

(However, my code is running in a MSCRM 2011 custom workflow activity)

My code is:

```
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
        parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://mySPServer/sites/scans/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/MyRepositoryIDGUID?getRepositoryInfo";
        parameters[SessionParameter.User] = "MyUser";
        parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = "MyPassword";
        parameters[SessionParameter.AuthenticationProviderClass] = "DotCMIS.Binding.NtlmAuthenticationProvider";

        var sessionFactory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
        return sessionFactory.GetRepositories(parameters)[0].CreateSession();
```

**However whenever I run it I am currently getting the following exception:**

Sif General Error: DotCMIS.Exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Could not load authentictaion provider: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at DotCMIS.Binding.Impl.CmisBinding..ctor(IDictionary`2 sessionParameters, AbstractAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotCMIS.Binding.Impl.CmisBinding..ctor(IDictionary`2 sessionParameters, AbstractAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider)
   at DotCMIS.Client.Impl.CmisBindingHelper.CreateAtomPubBinding(IDictionary`2 parameters, AbstractAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider)
   at DotCMIS.Client.Impl.SessionFactory.GetRepositories(IDictionary`2 parameters, IObjectFactory objectFactory, AbstractAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, ICache cache)
   at TPR.SIF.WorkflowActivity.SessionService.CreateNewSession(String dmWebServiceUrl, String userName, String password)
   at TPR.SIF.WorkflowActivity.SifService.SetUpServices(CodeActivityContext codeActivityContext)
   at TPR.SIF.WorkflowActivity.SifService.Execute(CodeActivityContext codeActivityContext)

The error happens on the following line:

```
  sessionFactory.GetRepositories(parameters)[0].CreateSession();
```

which calls this line in the CMIS library

```
       if (sessionParameters.TryGetValue(SessionParameter.AuthenticationProviderClass, out authenticationProviderClass))
            {
                try
                {
                    Type authProvType = Type.GetType(authenticationProviderClass);
                     authenticationProvider = (AbstractAuthenticationProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(authProvType);
```

Does anyone know why **"DotCMIS.Binding.NtlmAuthenticationProvider"** cannot be created?

Thanks very much.

Sean.

Comment: i also got a related error, i also need help for this too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382247/getrepositoriesparameters-throws-cmisruntimeexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTLM support will released with DotCMIS 0.5. If you are using DotCMIS 0.4, it cannot work.

Comment: Thanks! yes I just saw this comment (since 0.5) = DotCMIS.Binding.NtlmAuthenticationProvider). Do you have a download link for 0.5?

Comment: DotCMIS 0.5 is not released, yet. You have to grab the source code and build it yourself.

Comment: thanks. I have just found the 2 updated classes here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-531