# GetRepositories(parameters) throws CmisRuntimeException

Tags: c#, alfresco, dotcmis

**Hi Everyone,**

I'm currently trying to Connect to Alfresco (DMS), using DotCMIS/C#, so that I can create/locate/retrieve/archive files from it through my program.

Reference: https://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/getting-started-with-dotcmis.html

Note: I tried different "AtomPubUrl" to test which URL might work.

**[CMIS v1.0]**
For Alfresco Version 3.x: *http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/service/cmis* 
For Alfresco 4.0.x and Alfresco 4.1.x :  *http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/cmisatom*

For Alfresco 4.2: *http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom*

**[CMIS v1.1]**
For Alfresco 4.2: *http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom*

Here's my code:

> `Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();`
>   `parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;`
>   
>   `//parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis";` 
> **//Throws: "Not Found**
>   
>   `//parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom";` 
> **//Throws: "Unauthorized**
>   
>   `//parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom";` 
> **//Throws: "Unauthorized**
>   
>   `//parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom";` 
> **//Throws: "Unauthorized**
>   
>   `parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.User] = "admin ";`
>   `parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.Password] = "admin";`
>   `SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();` 
>   `ISession session = factory.GetRepositories(parameters)[0].CreateSession();`

Before, I encountered an exception CmisRuntimeException - "**SendFailure**", but now it changes into "**Not Found**"/"**Unauthorized**".

Can somebody explain me why am I encountering these errors? or What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards!

Have a nice day.

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you trying to talk to?

Comment: Hi Gagravarr, my installer said "alfresco-enterprise-5.0.0.5-installer-win-x64".

Comment: Alfresco 5.0 uses 4.2-style URLs, so the other ones will never work. Try with just `http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom` and a valid username + password for your server

Answer (score 0):

Promoting a comment to an answer

You need to use the correct CMIS Service URL for the version of Alfresco you are running. Trying to use the 3.x URL on a 5.x server isn't likely to work. You can find the CMIS service URL for a given version in that version's documentation, or you can get an overview of all the URLs from the [Alfresco Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#CMIS_Service_URL)

Secondly, you'll need to be authenticating to the CMIS server. You don't have to use admin, but you do need to use valid credentials

Assuming you have a 4.2 server, with an administrator account called `admin` and a password of `admin`, you would want something like

```
parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom";
parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.User] = "admin ";
parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.Password] = "admin";
SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
ISession session = factory.GetRepositories(parameters)[0].CreateSession();
```