# Connecting to Alfresco Repository using cmis C#

Tags: c#, alfresco

Hello I am new to alfresco, am trying to connect to alfresco repository using CMIS C# but this create an error while it tries to create session here is my C# function.

```
public void connecttofirstrepository()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
    parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl]= "http://172.20.0.113:8080/alfresco/service/cmis";
    parameters[SessionParameter.User] = "username";
    parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = "password";
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
    ISession session = factory.GetRepositories(parameters)[0].CreateSession();                   
}
```

It shows the following error

> {"ExceptionMessage": "Not Found", "ExceptionType": DotCMIS.Exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException", "StackTrace": "at DotCMIS.Binding.AtomPub.AbstractAtomPubService.Read(UrlBuild‌​er url) at DotCMIS.Binding.AtomPub.AbstractAtomPubService.GetRepositori‌​esInternal(String repositoryId) at DotCMIS.Binding.Impl.BindingRepositoryService.GetRepositoryI‌​nfos(IExtensionsData extension) at DotCMIS.Client.Impl.SessionFactory.GetRepositories(IDictiona‌​ry`2 parameters, IObjectFactory objectFactory, AbstractAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, ICache cache)

Comment: What errors? Without knowing that it's hard for us to help you...

Comment: this is the error on the stack trace {"ExceptionMessage": "Not Found",
  "ExceptionType": DotCMIS.Exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException",
  "StackTrace": "at DotCMIS.Binding.AtomPub.AbstractAtomPubService.Read(UrlBuilder url)   at DotCMIS.Binding.AtomPub.AbstractAtomPubService.GetRepositoriesInternal(String repositoryId) at DotCMIS.Binding.Impl.BindingRepositoryService.GetRepositoryInfos(IExtensionsData extension) at DotCMIS.Client.Impl.SessionFactory.GetRepositories(IDictionary`2 parameters, IObjectFactory objectFactory, AbstractAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, ICache cache)

Comment: did you see this post [Connect with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941809/connecting-via-cmis-dotcmis-to-sp2010-exception-unauthorised)

Comment: also try to change your AtomPubUrl to `"http://" + ipAlfresco + "/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom";`

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to use the correct CMIS service URL for your version of Alfresco as it has changed several times across releases.

See [the wiki](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5527-cmis) for a list of CMIS service URLs by version.